# How to disable other applications also desktop applications in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, boot, services, desktop

I want to disable unused programs and services also desktop application in Raspberry Pi except my own program to gain performance from RAM. I searched on the web and found some information. 
To disable services use the command:

```
update-rc.d <Servicename> disable
```

or to remove use:

```
update-rc.d -f the-service remove
```

we can remove unused programs and we can make our program to run at start up. Are these enough to make our pi special for our aim or are there any other things to do?

Comment: use Raspbian Jessie-lite distro if you don't need the Desktop applications.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a Linux distro that is minimal from start, like:

   - https://minibianpi.wordpress.com
   - http://dietpi.com/
2. And the command, `service --status-all` will show all services on your RasPi